# Why is scala.meta.Term.Param#toString dropping modifiers?

Tags: scala, scalameta, scalafix

I'm trying to rename the parameter of an anonymous function using a semantic scalafix plugin. The relevant code looks like this:

```scala
  case Term.Apply(func, args) =>
    args.collect { case Term.Block(List(Term.Function(List(arg), _))) =>
      Patch.replaceTree(arg, arg.copy(name = Term.Name("components")).toString())
```

The problem is, this is changing `{ implicit foo =>` to `{ components =>` (i.e. it's dropping the `implicit` modifier). I initially thought it was being dropped by the `copy` method for some reason, but I added some `println`s and that's not the case: the `implicit` modifier exists on the copy, but just isn't being included in the `toString` output. Anyone know what's going on here? And how I can get the `implicit` to be included in the output?

`println`s:

```scala
      println("***********ORIGINAL***********")
      println("toString:\t" + arg.toString())
      println("name:\t\t" + arg.name)
      println("modifiers:\t" + arg.mods)
      println("syntax:\t\t" + arg.syntax)
      println("structure:\t" + arg.structure)
      println("***********COPY***********")
      val copy = arg.copy(name = Term.Name("components"))
      println("toString:\t" + copy.toString())
      println("name:\t\t" + copy.name)
      println("modifiers:\t" + copy.mods)
      println("syntax:\t\t" + copy.syntax)
      println("structure:\t" + copy.structure)
```

output:

```
***********ORIGINAL***********
toString:   implicit app
name:       app
modifiers:  List(implicit)
syntax:     implicit app
structure:  Term.Param(List(Mod.Implicit), Term.Name("app"), None, None)
***********COPY***********
toString:   components
name:       components
modifiers:  List(implicit)
syntax:     components
structure:  Term.Param(List(Mod.Implicit), Term.Name("components"), None, None)
```

(notice that the `copy` has `implicit` in its list of modifiers, but it doesn't show up in the outputs of `toString` or `syntax`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that when Scalameta (4.5.13) prints a `Term.Param` it [skips](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/main/scalameta/trees/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/prettyprinters/TreeSyntax.scala#L604-L606) `Mod.Implicit` and `Mod.Using`

```
  case t: Term.Param =>
    // NOTE: `implicit/using` in parameters is skipped as it applies to whole list
    printParam(t, t.mods.filterNot(x => x.is[Mod.Implicit] || x.is[Mod.Using]))
```

Then it prints `List[List[Term.Param]]` [correctly](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/v4.5.13/scalameta/trees/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/prettyprinters/TreeSyntax.scala#L1196-L1213)

```
implicit def syntaxParamss: Syntax[List[List[Term.Param]]] = Syntax { paramss =>
  def usingImplicit(params: List[Term.Param]): Show.Result = {
    if (params.exists(_.mods.exists(_.is[Mod.Using])))
      s("using ", r(params, ", "))
    else
      w("implicit ", r(params, ", "), params.exists(_.mods.exists(_.is[Mod.Implicit])))
  }
  r(
    paramss.map(params => {
      s(
        "(",
        usingImplicit(params),
        ")"
      )
    }),
    ""
  )
}
```

but this doesn't help us.

The easiest fix is just to add `implicit` when necessary

```
doc.tree.collect {
  case Term.Apply(func, args) =>
    args.collect {
      case Term.Block(List(Term.Function(List(arg), _))) =>
        val res = arg.copy(name = Term.Name("components"))
        val prefix = if (res.mods.exists(_.is[Mod.Implicit])) "implicit " else ""
        Patch.replaceTree(arg, prefix + res.toString)
    }.asPatch
}.asPatch
```

---

> why it's printed in the original but not in the copy though

Because Scalameta prints differently newly parsed trees and transformed/generated trees. For the former it preserves their original string representation with original formatting. For the latter it prints them with corresponding instance of `scala.meta.prettyprinters.Show` i.e. skips `implicit` for a parameter etc.

`arg.toString` calls `scala.meta.internal.prettyprinters.TreeSyntax.apply[Term.Param](Scala213).apply(arg)`.

The [method](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/main/scalameta/trees/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/prettyprinters/TreeSyntax.scala#L1208-L1222) `TreeSyntax.apply` is

```
def apply[T <: Tree](dialect: Dialect): Syntax[T] = {
  // NOTE: This is the current state of the art of smart prettyprinting.
  // If we prettyprint a tree that's just been parsed with the same dialect,
  // then we retain formatting. Otherwise, we don't, even in the tiniest.
  // I expect to improve on this in the nearest future, because we had it much better until recently.
  Syntax { (x: T) =>
    x.origin match {
      // NOTE: Options don't really matter,
      // because if we've parsed a tree, it's not gonna contain lazy seqs anyway.
      // case Origin.Parsed(_, originalDialect, _) if dialect == originalDialect && options == Options.Eager =>
      case o @ Origin.Parsed(_, `dialect`, _) => s(o.position.text)
      case _ => reprint(x)(dialect)
    }
  }
}
```

Here in the pattern matching for `Origin.Parsed` (the origin of a newly parsed tree) the method returns `Result.Str`, for `Origin.None` (the origin of a transformed/generated tree) it returns `Result.Sequence`.

```
println(arg) // implicit y: Boolean
println(arg.structure) // Term.Param(List(Mod.Implicit), Term.Name("y"), Some(Type.Name("Boolean")), None)
println(arg.getClass) // class scala.meta.Term$Param$TermParamImpl
println(arg.origin) // Parsed(Input.VirtualFile("fix/Scalafixdemo.scala", "... implicit y: Boolean => ..."),Scala213,TokenStreamPosition(45,51))
println(TreeSyntax.apply[Term.Param](Scala213).apply(arg).getClass) 
// class scala.meta.prettyprinters.Show$Str

val res = arg.copy(name = Term.Name("components"))
println(res) // components: Boolean
println(res.structure) // Term.Param(List(Mod.Implicit), Term.Name("components"), Some(Type.Name("Boolean")), None)
println(res.getClass) // class scala.meta.Term$Param$TermParamImpl
println(res.origin) // None
println(TreeSyntax.apply[Term.Param](Scala213).apply(res).getClass) 
// class scala.meta.prettyprinters.Show$Sequence
```

The method `scala.meta.internal.trees.InternalTree#origin` is `private[meta]` so if you play with it put your rule into the package `scala.meta`.

`Term.Param` is not a case class and `.copy` is not a method of a case class. `arg` and `res` are actually instances of macro-generated class `Term.Param.TermParamImpl`.

Comment: Hmm. Not printing implicit or using makes sense, given that they do apply to the whole list. That doesn't explain why it's printed in the original but not in the copy though